# How can I configure my network adapter after installing VS with the WP8 SDK?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8

This is a fresh Windows installation with VS 2013 Update 2 installed. During installation I ticked the checkbox to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK. That caused the installation of a Hyper-V VM, which seems to have taken over my network connections.

This is what I have when the network cable is plugged in:

- Ethernet
  Enabled
  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)
  Unidentified network
- vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch)
  Network

This is what I have when the network cable is unplugged, changes in bold:

- Ethernet
  **Network cable unplugged**
  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)
  Unidentified network
- vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch)
  **Network cable unplugged**

Now the problem is I want to change the DNS settings of my real network adapter. I think it's the first one, unless the real one is somehow hidden. In its properties, everything but *Hyper-V Virtual Switch* is unchecked.

How can I change the settings I want now? Do I need to go through Hyper-V Manager?

Comment: It's the device without the word "virtual" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation of what happens on [Server Fault: Hyper-V extensible virtual switch disables network](https://serverfault.com/q/444107/63518)

The key line:

> the physical NIC gets bound with the Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Protocol (which is the virtual switch driver)

That prompted me to try and change the settings of the *vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch)* adapter (third one in the question). I changed the DNS servers for IPv4 and IPv6 and it works. My browser uses the DNS servers I've chosen and `nslookup` also uses them.

```
C:\Users\Stijn>nslookup superuser.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  2001:4860:4860::8888

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    superuser.com
Address:  198.252.206.140
```